# I have 4 title_announcement. but only one title_announcement appears. how to get all the titles to show up?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

my controller

```
$data['judul'] = $this->pengumuman->getJudul($id_announcement);
```

my model

```
public function getJudul($id_announcement)
    {
        $this->db->select('mp.id_announcement, mp.title_announcement, mp.isi_pengumuman')
        ->from('tbl_mst_pengumuman mp')
        ->order_by('mp.id_announcement','DESC' ,$id_announcement)
        ->limit(3);
        return $this->db->get()->row();
    }
```

my view

```
<div class="portlet-body">
        <div id="nt-example1-container">
          <ul id="nt-example1" class="news">
            <li>
                <b><a href="<?= site_url('login/pengumuman/detail/'.@$judul->id_announcement); ?>" class="link_pengumuman"><?= $judul->title_announcement ?></a></b>
                <?= $judul->isi_pengumuman ?>
                <li><br>
                <b><a href="<?= site_url('login/pengumuman/detail/'.@$judul->id_announcement); ?>" class="link_pengumuman"><?= $judul->title_announcement ?></a></b>
                <?= $judul->isi_pengumuman ?>
                </li><br>
                 <li>
                <b><a href="<?= site_url('login/pengumuman/detail/'.@$judul->id_announcement); ?>" class="link_pengumuman"><?= $judul->title_announcement ?></a></b>
                <?= $judul->isi_pengumuman ?>
                </li> <br>
                <li>
                <b><a href="<?= site_url('login/pengumuman/detail/'.@$judul->id_announcement); ?>" class="link_pengumuman"><?= $judul->title_announcement ?></a></b>
                <?= $judul->isi_pengumuman ?>
                </li><br>
              </div>
            </div>
```

note : on the view I've tried to show. I do not know if it's wrong in syntax.

*sory my english so bad

Comment: side note - you have some invalid syntax. you never close your 1st `<li>` or your `<ul>`. and `<br>` is not a valid child of `<ul>` -> `</li><br><li>`.

Comment: You need to run a foreach to loop through your content. If you echo out the variable then it will always show the same result :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
foreach($results as $value) {
    echo "<li>";
    // your code
    echo "</li>";
}
</ul>
```

Don't use br between each li, use css instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$this->db->get()->row()` function, it will return only 1 row, 
you should you `$this->db->get()->result()`

also, you are passing `$id_announcement` inside the `order_by()`, it's wrong, i think `$id_announcement` will be a `id` for filtering the result by `id_announcement`

so, your model function should be like below

```
    public function getJudul($id_announcement)
        {
            $this->db->select('mp.id_announcement, mp.title_announcement, mp.isi_pengumuman')
            ->from('tbl_mst_pengumuman mp')
            ->where('mp.id_announcement', $id_announcement)
            ->limit(3)
            ->order_by('mp.id_announcement','DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : false;
        }
```

in view file add like this

```
<?php if($judul){ ?>
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div id="nt-example1-container">    
        <ul id="nt-example1" class="news">
        <?php foreach($judul as $row){ ?>
            <li>
                <b><a href="<?= site_url('login/pengumuman/detail/'.$row->id_announcement); ?>" class="link_pengumuman"><?= $row->title_announcement; ?></a></b>
                <?= $row->isi_pengumuman; ?>
            </li>   
        <?php } ?>          
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }else{ echo 'no records found!'; } ?>
```